# "If you or somebody you know" vs "If somebody you know or you"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, word-order, coordinating-conjunctions

The following sentence makes sense:

- *If you or somebody you know is an experienced such-and-such, please contact us.*

However, reversing the subjects (and choosing "are" based on the [proximity rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187779/55308)) makes it sound extremely awkward:

- *If somebody you know or you are an experienced such-and-such, please contact us.*

The is/are verb choice does not really matter, placing "somebody you know" first makes the sentence difficult to read and awkward to say. However, switching subjects in a compound subject doesn't always "ruin" the sentence, e.g.:

- *If your dog or your cat is sick, call the vet.*
- *If your cat or your dog is sick, call the vet.*

My question is: What is wrong with "If somebody you know or you"? Is this violating some grammatical rule? Why is this sentence so hard to parse? I know it doesn't "feel" right but I'd like to know why.

Comment: Your other examples do not match your initial example. _If x and something related to x_

Comment: @mplungjan In thinking about your comment I think I might have a guess as to why swapping the subjects in the first example doesn't work. Is it because the "you" in "somebody you know" is somehow a different kind of pronoun that refers back to the first isolated "you", sort of like "Bob and his dog" means Bob's dog but "His dog and Bob" doesn't connect "his" to "Bob's" any more? What is the difference between the "you" in the two subjects; I know there is one I just don't know what it is, or the terminology.

Comment: Wait a minute! The first sentence you propose, "If you or someone you know *is* an experienced such-and-such, please contact us." would not pass muster with any of my English teachers. If you leave out the "or someone you know" bit, the sentence reduces to "If you ... is an experienced such-and-such, please contact us." That would have rated a drop of a full letter grade, because "you" conjugates with "are", not is. (Continued next comment)

Comment: @brasshat Stop right there and see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/187779/55308.

Comment: (Continued from previous comment)  If you leave yourself out of consideration, for a moment, the sentence reduces to "If someone you know ... is an experienced such-and-such, please contact us.", then "is" is appropriate. Jason, the difference between the two uses of "you" is that the standalone one is a stand alone pronoun; in "someone you know", you is modifying "someone", by specifying the subset of all possible someones as the ones you know.

Comment: I'd say the awkwardness you feel is due to word order. We normally say *If you or a loved one/member of your family*; *If you or your spouse/children/family* etc. Inverting the order will sound odd, but it won't affect the grammaticality. Whereas changing the pronoun to "I" the word order is usually reversed. *If my spouse/children/family or I were ...*

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see; so the "awkwardness" is just because it's different than the pattern I'm used to hearing, rather than incorrect structure or grammar; still, there must be some linguistic reason why "you or somebody you know" became the *exclusive* choice of the two options, right? There doesn't really seem to be anybody that arbitrarily prefers "somebody you know or you". I.e. does it feel awkward because it's not the normal choice, or is it not the normal choice because it "feels awkward" for a deeper reason?

Comment: Well why do we say "a black and white photo" and not the other way round? "Quiet and peace" makes sense but sounds odd, "mum" nearly always comes before "dad" in "My mum and dad" etc. When placing "you" ahead of a list I suppose we are aiming our focus on that subject and the "somebody you know" is a logical sequence, which btw would include any family, friend or acquaintance. On the other hand, it's considered rude/arrogant to place oneself in front of a statement, hence even queen Elizabeth says: "My husband and I" :)

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct. However, as you point out, it *feels* awkward, mainly because `somebody you know` is a superset of `you` (assuming that you do, in fact, know yourself). Translating it to your second example, would you ever say the following?

> If your pet or your dog is sick, call the vet.

Comment: Is "somebody you know" a superset of "you"? I could just say "If somebody you know is..." to mean a friend of yours but not you. Also the example doesn't seem to have the same subject switching quality -- "If your dog or your pet is sick" isn't an improvement and is still awkward for the same reason. It seems more related to using the first subject after a "that" (or whatever) in the second (but I don't know the word for that), e.g. "if your dog or something that your dog ate is" vs "if something that your dog ate or your dog is".

Comment: Yes, it is. If it still *feels wrong*, it's for the opposite relation between the subjects: generalization rather than specialization. You're much more likely to see the former than the latter. (On a side note, you could say that, but you may be misunderstood. If i ask you `Is someone you know called Jason C?` I *would* expect to hear the answer `Yes, I am called Jason C`)

Comment: Thanks. Hm; the answer you'd get from me would honestly be "No, but *I* am called Jason C!" I guess it's all very fuzzy and open to interpretation. It makes sense though, but I'm still not quite convinced mainly because switching "your pet" and "your dog" doesn't "fix" your example, but switching "you" and "somebody you know" has a huge effect - and that's the effect I don't understand. There's a major difference between my first and second example but I don't know what it is; *mplungjan* hinted at it in a comment on the question.

Comment: Well if you only had to answer with yes/no, i'd still expect a "yes". You're right, I guess, it depends. As for the switching, the exact correlation would go as `Your dog or another pet` which sounds much less awkward than `Another of your pets or your dog`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall learning
(as a cultural courtesy / politeness / etiquette convention,
but not necessarily a grammar rule) that, when listing people,
it is preferable to put the person or people you are addressing
(the second person: “you”) first, 
yourself (the first person: “I” and “me”, and, arguably, “we” and “us”) last, 
and all others between. 
For example,

- “You, Fred, Ginger and I need to write the report.”
- “Harry assigned it to you, Fred, Ginger and me.”
- “You, they and I need to write the report.”

There is a lot of support for the “me last” guideline. 
I haven’t been able to find much support for the “you first” convention;
here’s what I found:

- [Randall Stewart’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/304675/26083#305617) to
  [Why do personal pronouns always come last after a list of nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/304675/26083)

  > You list the person you are speaking directly to first, yourself last, 
  >   and everyone else in between: “You, Bob, Mary, and I were the only ones left.”
- [Ordering first, second and third persons – WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ordering-first-second-and-third-persons.2259587)

  > The **first** person must be (i) **the person to whom you are talking,**
  >   (ii) conventionally, "I" will be the last.

  The credibility of this source is tainted by the fact that,
  in a discussion about first person pronouns and second person pronouns,
  it uses the phrase “first person”
  to refer to the first pronoun to appear in the list.

The point is, I (and some other people?)
find “you and Fred” to be more natural and polite than “Fred and you”. 
Same with “you *or* Fred” over “Fred *or* you”. 
So that might be a partial reason why people find “somebody you know or you”
to be awkward.